# Check if plane intersects cuboid

Tags: geometry

How to check if a cuboid of known vertices and a plane of equation $ax + by + cz + d = 0$ intersects?

Comment: A point $P=(x,y,z)$ lies on either side of the given plane according to the sign of $ax+by+cz+d$. And the plane intersects the cuboid iff at least two of its vertices lie on opposite sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is probably to check whether all vertices are on the same side of the plane or not.

The two half-spaces formed by the plane are respectively such that $ax+by+cz+d > 0$ and $<0$. So calculating  $ax+by+cz+d$ for each vertex gives you the answer.